# Routing in ASP.NET with numerical constraint path

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing

I'm trying to route a specific path made of a numerical value and a string to a specific aspx page.

I have the following routing code initialized in the global.asax.cs file:

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {


        routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "{id}/{name}", "~/item.aspx",
        true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", @"\d+"} }
        );

    }
```

I have an item.aspx page as well.

1) When I  try to access the page using this url:

```
http://localhost:8895/1/test/
```

I get **404 error**

2) I also tried adding the name to the `RouteValueDictionary` like so:

```
new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", @"\d+" }, { "name", @"[a-z0-9-]+" } }
```

3) In another try I put null in the defaults parameter:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "{id}/{name}", "~/item.aspx",
        true,
        null,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", @"\d+" }, { "name", @"[a-z0-9-]+" } }
        );
```

But I still get 404 error.

I am developing in ASP.NET 4.5/C#/Visual Studio 2013

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define in route value dictionary the param name too.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón How can I do that for any string?

Comment: @AlbertoLeónI try that without any luck. I updated the question with the sample coded I used. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Your question answered my answer.

Comment: I have done exactly what you have done here, and it works.

Question: Do you have multiple routes? Can you paste your entire RegisterRoutes method?

Question: Can you verify (several times) that ~/item.aspx actually exists? It is spelled correctly, and is at the root of the website? If there is a spelling error it will give a 404.